# How to add splash screen on custom linux(specially raspberry pi)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, embedded-linux, buildroot

I currently have a project so basically what i want is to create an embedded linux in raspberry pi. What i want to achieve is to boot my custom made linux in my raspberry pi. I'm currently using Buildroot for that.

Here are the things what i want to happen:

1. Create a splash screen(How to implement this? What are the files on linux needed to edit. )

   2. Override login prompt after booting(I want to  use my own prompt which is i already created using python. What i want here is after booting my python app will be the first one to display)
   3. Display my python application after booting.

WHAT files/configurations i need to know.
HOW  to implement this. Process or a work flow.

Just like osmc or kido but i want to build my own also from scratch. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is really more a *configuration* question than a *programming* question.

Comment: @Chris Stratton hmm. any idea?

Comment: What I mean is that this is the wrong site, belongs on unix se or similar.  Also you really should be specific about the window manager / etc in use

Comment: @Chris Stratton i will not use any window manager for this kind of project. As i want to happen is to display my python gui application after booting. I'm currently using the linux kernel provided by raspberry pi.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand the operation of the system you are working with, or GUI's on Linux in general.  Either that, or you've left too much critical information out of your question for it be answerable even on a site where it might be on topic, something that it is not here.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple components involved in splash screen. One is what you can display when u-boot starts and then the kernel takes over. You can get some information [here](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Linux_Boot_Logo) and [here](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=U-Boot_Splash_Screen). Both require re compilation of u-boot and Linux kernel. May be even some more additional steps depending on system. Also note this transition is not going to be smooth, between the logo displayed by u-boot and then the kernel.

On desktops, this is generally taken care of by software like [Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/).

From what I understand, you want your python application to auto start after booting. Have a look at writing a systemd service for that as described [here](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-autorun-application-at-the-start-up-in-linux#Daemons).